# Changing the width of my bxslider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bxslider somehow has a fixed width of about 1000. The picture does not fit the bxslider frame. How do i adjust the bxslider width to lets say 700px.

My website: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't the slider itself, it's just expanding to the column width. You need to shrink the column itself. Change:

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
```

To:

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
```

Answer (score 0):

you could set the width of your image to 100%

```
<li style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; position: relative; width: 898px;">
  <img width="100%" height="210" src="img/Day1.jpg">
</li>
```

so that your image will fill it's container

Comment: What if i want to change the width of the container itself?

Comment: than user: AlliterativeAlice has your answer `<div class="col-xs-7">`

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS rule (before `</head>`):

```
<style>
    .bx-wrapper img { width: 100%; }
</style>
```